# IllegalArgumentException: Bad endianness tag while getting number of pages of a tiff file

Tags: java, tiff, endianness, jai

I'm getting a weird error while manipulating a tiff file. I already do something similar with other file formats and even other tiff files. But out of the sudden, I got the following message:

```
Bad endianness tag (not 0x4949 or 0x4d4d).
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad endianness tag (not 0x4949 or 0x4d4d).
at com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFDirectory.getNumDirectories(TIFFDirectory.java:588)
at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFImageDecoder.getNumPages(TIFFImageDecoder.java:105)
at br.com.org.sofia.util.PdfUtil.gerarPDFATiff(PdfUtil.java:213)
at br.com.GerarControler.gerarPDFA(GerarControler.java:182)
at br.com.controller.IndexadorControle.indexarUpload(IndexadorControle.java:331)
at br.com.controller.IndexadorControle.indexarUpload(IndexadorControle.java:289)
at sofia.control.BuscaUploadController$7.call(BuscaUploadController.java:720)
at sofia.control.BuscaUploadController$7.call(BuscaUploadController.java:703)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The java class:

```
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;

public class PdfUtil {

...

  Path path = Paths.get(getInput()); //getInput() returns a string path to the tiff file
  byte[] tiffImage = Files.readAllBytes(path);

  ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tiffImage);
  ImageDecoder tiffDecoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", inputStream, null);
  int pages = tiffDecoder.getNumPages();
...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the file has a bad endianness tag.

Comment: Are you sure the file you are dealing with is in fact a tiff file and not some other image format?

Comment: As @MichaelKrause suggests, this is most likely not a TIFF file. Can you attach the problematic file? Or if you can't, at least include the first 4-16 bytes as hex values in your question? This should normally be enough to tell the file format. A TIFF file *must* start with the values `0x4949` or `0x4d4d` followed by the number 42 in the endianness indicated by the first two bytes.